# Accessing the left margin setting in beamer

Tags: beamer

I have an element in the footline that I want to left-align with the frame contents.
I have tried using `\Gm@lmargin` in various ways, but I always get an "undefined control sequence" error. Here is an example of what I've tried.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\title{Sample Presentation}

\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{custom}[1][]
{
  \begin{beamercolorbox}{footline}
    \hspace{\Gm@lmargin} % Gives me "undefined control sequence"
    This text should be left aligned with the frame contents

    THIS WILL BE A GRAPHIC THAT SPANS THE WIDTH OF THE WHOLE PAGE
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{My frame title}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, and so on and so forth.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I tried looking at how some of the templates use this variable, but the examples I found were difficult for me to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\gm@lmargin` contains an `@` sign, this means you need to enclose the definition of your template in `\makeatletter ... \makeatother`, see the linked question at the very top of your question to learn why (and you have one space too much after the `\hspace`):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\title{Sample Presentation}

\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{custom}[1][]
{
  \begin{beamercolorbox}{footline}
    \hspace{\Gm@lmargin}% Gives me "undefined control sequence"
    This text should be left aligned with the frame contents

    THIS WILL BE A GRAPHIC THAT SPANS THE WIDTH OF THE WHOLE PAGE
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{My frame title}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, and so on and so forth.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]